# Runtime error using WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

What I wanted to do is make a particular string in a combobox the selectedindex. The contents of the combobox are filenames of files ina directory. This is an editable combobox.
So I did

```
private void InitComboBoxProfiles()
{
    string appDataPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string configPath1 = appDataPath1 + "/LWRF/ReaderProfiles";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(configPath1);
    foreach( string fn in files)
    {
        ComboBoxProfiles.Items.Add(fn);

    }
    int index = -1;
    foreach (ComboBoxItem cmbItem in ComboBoxProfiles.Items) //exception thrown at this line
    {
        index++;
        if (cmbItem.Content.ToString() == "Default.xml")
        {
            ComboBoxProfiles.SelectedIndex = index;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Exception:

> Unable to cast object of type System.String to
>   System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem

How do I achieve my goal?
thanks,
saroj

Answer (score 1):

As the ComboBox items are strings, you could simply set the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property to the desired string:

```
ComboBoxProfiles.SelectedItem = "Default.xml";
```

---

Note that this will automatically set the `SelectedIndex` property to the proper value, as `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` will always be kept in sync.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you, AbZy and Clemens! I used your idea Clemens and it worked like a charm and I learned something new!Many Thanks, saroj

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox` Items are of type `string`. Change your code to this :

```
foreach (string cmbItem in ComboBoxProfiles.Items) 
    {
        index++;
        if (cmbItem == "Default.xml")
        {
            ComboBoxProfiles.SelectedIndex = index;
            break;
        }
    }
```

and better than looping :

```
ComboBoxProfiles.SelectedIndex = ComboBoxProfiles.Items.IndexOf("Default.xml");
```